# How to upload file in my chat with document web app using Openai api key

Tags: next.js

I am getting an error:

> Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
>
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

This is my core.ts code:

```
import { db } from "@/db";
import { getKindeServerSession } from "@kinde-oss/kinde-auth-nextjs/server";
import { createUploadthing, type FileRouter } from "uploadthing/next";

import { PDFLoader } from "langchain/document_loaders/fs/pdf";
import { OpenAIEmbeddings } from "langchain/embeddings/openai";
import { PineconeStore } from "langchain/vectorstores/pinecone";
import { getPineconeClient } from "@/lib/pinecone";
import { getUserSubscriptionPlan } from "@/lib/stripe";
import { PLANS } from "@/config/stripe";

const f = createUploadthing();

const middleware = async () => {
  const { getUser } = getKindeServerSession();
  const user = getUser();

  if (!user || !user.id) throw new Error("Unauthorized");

  const subscriptionPlan = await getUserSubscriptionPlan();

  return { subscriptionPlan, userId: user.id };
};

const onUploadComplete = async ({
  metadata,
  file,
}: {
  metadata: Awaited<ReturnType<typeof middleware>>;
  file?: {
    key: string;
    name: string;
    url?: string;
  };
}) => {
    if (!file || !file.key || !file.name || !file.url) {
      console.error("Invalid 'file' object:", file);
      return;
    }
    
  const isFileExist = await db.file.findFirst({
    where: {
      key: file.key,
    },
  });

  if (isFileExist) return;

  const createdFile = await db.file.create({
    data: {
      key: file.key,
      name: file.name,
      userId: metadata.userId,
      url: file.url ? `https://uploadthing-prod.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/${file.key}`: '',
      uploadStatus: "PROCESSING",
    },
  });

  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://uploadthing-prod.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/${file.key}`
    );

    const blob = await response.blob();

    const loader = new PDFLoader(blob);

    const pageLevelDocs = await loader.load();

    const pagesAmt = pageLevelDocs.length;

    const { subscriptionPlan } = metadata;
    const { isSubscribed } = subscriptionPlan;

    const isProExceeded =
      pagesAmt > PLANS.find((plan) => plan.name === "Pro")!.pagesPerPdf;
    const isFreeExceeded =
      pagesAmt > PLANS.find((plan) => plan.name === "Free")!.pagesPerPdf;

    if ((isSubscribed && isProExceeded) || (!isSubscribed && isFreeExceeded)) {
      await db.file.update({
        data: {
          uploadStatus: "FAILED",
        },
        where: {
          id: createdFile.id,
        },
      });
    }

    // vectorize and index entire document
    const pinecone = await getPineconeClient();
    const pineconeIndex = pinecone.Index("quill");

    const embeddings = new OpenAIEmbeddings({
      openAIApiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
    });

    await PineconeStore.fromDocuments(pageLevelDocs, embeddings, {
      pineconeIndex,
      namespace: createdFile.id,
    });

    await db.file.update({
      data: {
        uploadStatus: "SUCCESS",
      },
      where: {
        id: createdFile.id,
      },
    });
  } catch (err) {
    await db.file.update({
      data: {
        uploadStatus: "FAILED",
      },
      where: {
        id: createdFile.id,
      },
    });
  }
};

export const ourFileRouter = {
  freePlanUploader: f({ pdf: { maxFileSize: "4MB" } })
    .middleware(middleware)
    .onUploadComplete(onUploadComplete),
  proPlanUploader: f({ pdf: { maxFileSize: "16MB" } })
    .middleware(middleware)
    .onUploadComplete(onUploadComplete),
} satisfies FileRouter;

export type OurFileRouter = typeof ourFileRouter;
```

I an getting an erorr:
⨯ TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'url')

I am also giving the code of my upload button for your reference:

```
"use client";

import { useState } from "react";
import { Dialog, DialogContent, DialogTrigger } from "./ui/dialog";
import { Button } from "./ui/button";

import Dropzone from "react-dropzone";
import { Cloud, File, Loader2 } from "lucide-react";
import { Progress } from "./ui/progress";
import { useUploadThing } from "@/lib/uploadthing";
import { useToast } from "./ui/use-toast";
import { trpc } from "@/app/_trpc/client";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

const UploadDropzone = ({ isSubscribed }: { isSubscribed: boolean }) => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const [isUploading, setIsUploading] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [uploadProgress, setUploadProgress] = useState<number>(0);
  const { toast } = useToast();

  const { startUpload } = useUploadThing(
    isSubscribed ? "proPlanUploader" : "freePlanUploader"
  );

  const { mutate: startPolling } = trpc.getFile.useMutation({
    onSuccess: (file) => {
      router.push(`/dashboard/${file.id}`);
    },
    retry: true,
    retryDelay: 500,
  });

  const startSimulatedProgress = () => {
    setUploadProgress(0);

    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setUploadProgress((prevProgress) => {
        if (prevProgress >= 95) {
          clearInterval(interval);
          return prevProgress;
        }
        return prevProgress + 5;
      });
    }, 500);

    return interval;
  };

  return (
    <Dropzone
      multiple={false}
      onDrop={async (acceptedFile) => {
        setIsUploading(true);

        const progressInterval = startSimulatedProgress();

        // handle file uploading
        const res = await startUpload(acceptedFile);

        if (!res) {
          return toast({
            title: "Something went wrong",
            description: "Please try again later",
            variant: "destructive",
          });
        }

        const [fileResponse] = res;

        const key = fileResponse?.key;

        if (!key) {
          return toast({
            title: "Something went wrong",
            description: "Please try again later",
            variant: "destructive",
          });
        }

        clearInterval(progressInterval);
        setUploadProgress(100);

        startPolling({ key });
      }}
    >
      {({ getRootProps, getInputProps, acceptedFiles }) => (
        <div
          {...getRootProps()}
          className="border h-64 m-4 border-dashed border-gray-300 rounded-lg"
        >
          <div className="flex items-center justify-center h-full w-full">
            <label
              htmlFor="dropzone-file"
              className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center w-full h-full rounded-lg cursor-pointer bg-gray-50 hover:bg-gray-100"
            >
              <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center pt-5 pb-6">
                <Cloud className="h-6 w-6 text-zinc-500 mb-2" />
                <p className="mb-2 text-sm text-zinc-700">
                  <span className="font-semibold">Click to upload</span> or drag
                  and drop
                </p>
                <p className="text-xs text-zinc-500">
                  PDF (up to {isSubscribed ? "16" : "4"}MB)
                </p>
              </div>

              {acceptedFiles && acceptedFiles[0] ? (
                <div className="max-w-xs bg-white flex items-center rounded-md overflow-hidden outline outline-[1px] outline-zinc-200 divide-x divide-zinc-200">
                  <div className="px-3 py-2 h-full grid place-items-center">
                    <File className="h-4 w-4 text-blue-500" />
                  </div>
                  <div className="px-3 py-2 h-full text-sm truncate">
                    {acceptedFiles[0].name}
                  </div>
                </div>
              ) : null}

              {isUploading ? (
                <div className="w-full mt-4 max-w-xs mx-auto">
                  <Progress
                    indicatorColor={
                      uploadProgress === 100 ? "bg-green-500" : ""
                    }
                    value={uploadProgress}
                    className="h-1 w-full bg-zinc-200"
                  />
                  {uploadProgress === 100 ? (
                    <div className="flex gap-1 items-center justify-center text-sm text-zinc-700 text-center pt-2">
                      <Loader2 className="h-3 w-3 animate-spin" />
                      Redirecting...
                    </div>
                  ) : null}
                </div>
              ) : null}

              <input
                {...getInputProps()}
                type="file"
                id="dropzone-file"
                className="hidden"
              />
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </Dropzone>
  );
};

const UploadButton = ({ isSubscribed }: { isSubscribed: boolean }) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);

  return (
    <Dialog
      open={isOpen}
      onOpenChange={(v) => {
        if (!v) {
          setIsOpen(v);
        }
      }}
    >
      <DialogTrigger onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)} asChild>
        <Button>Upload PDF</Button>
      </DialogTrigger>

      <DialogContent>
        <UploadDropzone isSubscribed={isSubscribed} />
      </DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
  );
};

export default UploadButton;
```

I am expecting that my file that i am trying to upload gets uploaded without any error.